# Side-by-side bar chart: One with the current filtered selection and one for total

Tags: tableau-api

I calculate the percent of total number of active customers for each SalesOwner in one of my Workbook sheets:

[image]

As you see, I have also added the SalesOwner as a filter.

The calculated field (`segment_active_members`) is computed using the following formula:

```
COUNTD(wk_customer)/ SUM({FIXED : COUNTD([wk_customer])})
```

What I want to do is create a side-by-side bar chart where upon filtering one of **SalesOwners**, I am able to compare it with the total (100%). So if I filter the above sheet by SalesOwner X which takes 5% of total. I'd like to see only two bars with one having 5% of the other one's length.

So I add another calculated filed to the above scenario where a fixed total is calculated:

```
SUM({FIXED : COUNTD([wk_customer])}
```

We will have a new column in the above picture with a fixed value of 100% for all rows.

I get what I want when my filter is on "All".

[image]

But as soon as I select a single filter (SalesOwner), my first percentage is also changed into 100% and I can never compare it to total.

[image]

How can I show the percentage against total for single segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one of the solution:

1. Change the calculation of `segment_active_members` as follows

   ```
   SUM({FIXED [Sales Owner]: COUNTD([wk_customer])})/SUM({COUNTD([wk_customer])})
   ```
2. Remove the table calculation for `segment_active_members` in the Measure Values shelf
   [image: as follows]

You'll see that you are able to filter it down without any problem now
[image]

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much!